# how to separate array first key from rest of the keys from array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this below array which I have got from Rubrics table, I am using one jquery extension which is giving me this below array  :-

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Identifies Dilemma
            [1] => Has a vague idea of what the dilemma is and is uncertain what must be decided
            [2] => Identifies the dilemma, including pertinent facts, and ascertains what must be decided
            [3] => Describes the dilemma in detail having gathered pertinent facts. Ascertains exactly what must be decided
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Considers Stakeholders
            [1] => Is unsure as to who should be involved in the decision-making process
            [2] => Determines who should be involved in the decision-making process and accurately identifies all the stakeholders
            [3] => Determines who should be involved in the decision-making process and thoroughly reflects on the viewpoints of the stakeholders
        )

)
```

The output I am trying to get is :-

```
[
'Identifies Dilemma' => [
            [1] => Has a vague idea of what the dilemma is and is uncertain what must be decided
            [2] => Identifies the dilemma, including pertinent facts, and ascertains what must be decided
            [3] => Describes the dilemma in detail having gathered pertinent facts. Ascertains exactly what must be decided
       
                        ]
],
[
'Considers Stakeholders' => [
         [1] => Is unsure as to who should be involved in the decision-making process
            [2] => Determines who should be involved in the decision-making process and accurately identifies all the stakeholders
            [3] => Determines who should be involved in the decision-making process and thoroughly reflects on the viewpoints of the stakeholders
      
       
                        ]
]
```

This is what I have tried so far but I do not want to use to many conditions if some php functions can help .

```
    $rubics = json_decode($model->rubric_json);
            $originalPoints = json_decode($model->points_json)[0];
            $rubicsCols = json_decode($model->rubric_json)[0];
            unset($rubics[0]);
            if (!empty($rubics)) {
                foreach ($rubics as $key => $data) {
                    $rows[] =  $data[0];
                }
            }
            
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($rubics);exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = [
   ['a','b','c'],
   ['a1','b1','c1']
];

$newArray = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $data) {
    $newKey = $data[0];
    unset($data[0]);
    $newArray[$newKey] = $data;
}

print_r($newArray);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
    (
        [1] => b
        [2] => c
    )

    [a1] => Array
    (
        [1] => b1
        [2] => c1
    )

)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks for the Quick response mate. God Bless